# OGG Encoder in C# or WinPRT compatible cx/c++

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to modifying libogg 1.3.0( from xiph.org) to support windows phone project which can be directly referenced inside any windows phone 8 project.

I have successfully compiled it with windows phone compilation and generated the dlls. But now these generated dlls cannot be directly used with windows phone as reference.

Can anyone help me with how I can compile this libogg project so that it supports windows phone runtime?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Windows Runtime Component (C++/CX) that wraps your C++ library. That will define what is seen from C#/.NET.

Comment: is there any quick book which helps id doing something like above?

Comment: If you haven't found help with this, I can help. I have need of your work on a project we're scoping out.